# How to import an object list from a javascript file to dynamic slug component in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have started using Next JS in my project. I have a list of projects in a separate js file. Projects are listed in my main page and when clicked on a project, I am navigating to the project details page. I have created `/pages/projects/[slug].js` to dynamically create pages and use project id in `Link`. I use `router.query.slug` to get the project id in the slug. I want to import the project list in the slug and choose the project. I am unable to reference the project's details from the imported projects list. I tried to `console.log` the project variable. In the browser console I get the project details, but in `VS code terminal` i get `undefined`. If I try to access project properties I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`.

My Slug:

```html
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import ProjectDetail from '../../components/projectdetails';
import '../../styles/globals.css'

const ProjectPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const projectid=(parseInt(router.query.slug,10));
  return (
    <>
    <ProjectDetail projectid={projectid} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ProjectPage;
```

My ProjectDetail component

```html
'use client';
import { Box, Paper, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import projectlist from '../utility/projectlist';

const ProjectDetail = ({projectid}=props) => {
  const project=projectlist[projectid];
  console.log(project.name);
  // const images = [...project.screenshot];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Box>
        
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectDetail;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `projectlist`?

Comment: This is weired: `{projectid}=props`. Try just with `{projectid}`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Seems the problem was using `app` directory in my project. I had my main page in that directory when the app was created. I got `undefined` value for project id all the time. I disabled it in `next.config.js` and created an `index.js` in `pages` directory and used `Link` query to pass the value and got the value in the slug

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your time. Seems the problem was using app directory in my project. I had my main page in that directory when the app was created. I got undefined value for `projectid` all the time. I disabled it in next.config.js and created an index.js in pages directory and used Link query to pass the value and got the value in the slug